# Google Indexed an Unlinked Page

Tags: web-crawler

Google indexed a page on a site of mine that was not linked from any other page, ever. No one has ever put a link to it, and the directory contents were not browsable. How could this happen? I thought crawlers have no way to include a page that is not linked.

Comment: Super User is intended for computer hardware and software related questions only.  Web services such as Google search are considered off-topic.  Please see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: Where should I put this question then?

Comment: Super User is not for every kind of question.  Take a look at this question for ideas.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions  Also this list may be useful.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't link to it, but how certain are you that no one else did? Someone sharing it on Facebook, Twitter, a public chat log, their personal site, etc. could do the trick.

If you don't want Google to index a page, block the Googlebot via robots.txt or some other technique. Relying solely on obscurity will bite you in the ass.

Comment: good point, thanks for that. I do not want to be ass-bitten.

Comment: @ceejayoz, my point was just to make sure that somebody somewhere had to share the link to get it indexed in Google (which was the case: in fact it was me in a past life). I was kind of checking the rules of the universe, too. At the same time, I did some investigation into making stuff not web-visible using GoDaddy, which was a useful result of your answer. Thanks again.